# SailsJs error with grabConnection(conn)

Tags: sails.js

Can someone help me with this SailsJs error

```
Running "less:dev" (less) task
verbose: Lowering sails...
verbose: Sent kill signal to child process (26729)...
../staging.platform/node_modules/sails-disk/lib/adapter.js:80
      grabConnection(conn).dropCollection(coll, relations, cb);
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'dropCollection' of undefined
    at Object.drop (../staging.platform/node_modules/sails-disk/lib/adapter.js:80:27)
    at module.exports.drop (../staging.platform/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/adapter/ddl/index.js:110:13)
    at afterAsyncEach (../staging.platform/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/adapter/sync/strategies/alter.js:190:14)
    at ../staging.platform/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (../staging.platform/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:236:30)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (../staging.platform/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:209:22)
    at ../staging.platform/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/adapter/sync/strategies/alter.js:134:13
    at wrapper (../staging.platform/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3592:19)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (../staging.platform/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:421:80)
    at wrappedCallback (../staging.platform/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:324:18)
    at success (../staging.platform/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/normalize.js:33:31)
    at _switch (../staging.platform/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/factory.js:58:28)
    at ../staging.platform/node_modules/sails-disk/lib/adapter.js:88:19
    at Timeout._onTimeout (../staging.platform/node_modules/sails-disk/lib/adapter.js:179:10)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

The problem I am having is, this error popped up without real cause. On my local machine my Sails App works - however, on my sandbox remote server, I just started getting the error...

I am completely at a lost...

Comment: Could be a permissions issue.  On the remote server, does the user that the Sails app is running under have permission to write files in the `.tmp` folder of the app?

Comment: I thought about that -- so I actually changed the .tmp to 777 and re-lifted Sails but it didn't work.

Comment: So I made a backup of localDB in the .tmp directory, and deleted the localDB and re-lifted Sails, which brought everything back up